# Missing Secure Attribute in Encrypted Session (SSL) Cookie Recheck

Tags: asp.net, security, session-cookies, httpcookie, penetration-testing

I tested web application with commercial tool for penetration test .I found a bug which is related to Missing Secure Attribute in Encrypted Session (SSL) Cookie.
Web application has written .Net . For this reason I added this content to web config:

```
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />
```

After that I checked application in browser with "Advanced Cookie Manager" add-on in Firefox.
Results of Advanced Cookie Manager
some attributes 
isSecure's value true, some attribute's IsSecure value false.
I want to re-check secure attribute.How can I do this?

Comment: For what it's worth, I have the same question!

Comment: I asked same question on security part of stack exchange.You can check this [page](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47869/missing-secure-attribute-in-encrypted-session-ssl-cookie-recheck)

Answer (score -1):

Try checking by clearing your browser cache and recheck